# How old was Tom Baker when he played the Fourth Doctor in Doctor Who?

Tags: doctor-who

I am wondering how old Tom Baker was when he played the Doctor. I know how old he is now, but how about then? I look up to him; he is my 3rd favourite doctor.

Comment: Here's why you got all those down votes: It took about 10 seconds to go to [IMBD](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0048982/?ref_=fn_al_nm_1) to look it up myself.

Answer (score 4):

### 40-47.

[Tom Baker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tom_Baker) was born on 20 January 1934, and he [played the Doctor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourth_Doctor) between 8 June 1974 and 21 March 1981.